# CSS ::before width that take parent's width of the generating element

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar (which contains 2 anchor elements) and I made this CSS animation with ::before and ::after that makes the background change dynamically with :hover. The problem is the background of the whole parent element changes and not only my navigation item.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100;300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');



*{
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
    outline: none;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

.navbar{
    display: flex;
    padding: 1rem 0;
    align-items: stretch;
    /* background-color: green; */
}

.container{
    display: flex;
    /* background-color: #1e1e2b; */
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 1152px;
}

.MonLogo_image{
    display: flex;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-buttons {
    /* background-color: rgb(0, 255, 255); */
    display:flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0.5em 1em;
}

.Monlogo{
    /* background-color: #ff4444; */
    position:relative;
}

.nav-bar-items{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    transition: .5s ease;
}

.material-symbols-outlined{
    /* background-color: rgb(230, 174, 174); */
    font-size: 2em;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
.nav-bar-item-container{
    width: 400px;
}

/** A partir de là c'est pour les transitions des boutons de navigations en haut */
.nav-bar-items::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0.1em;
    width: 0;
    background-color: rgb(228, 156, 22);
    transition: .5s ease;
}
  
.nav-bar-items:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}
  
.nav-bar-items:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}
  
.nav-bar-items::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(228, 156, 22);
    transition: .4s ease;
    z-index: -1;
}
  
.nav-bar-items:hover::after {
    height: 100%;
    transition-delay: 0.4s;
    color: #fff;
}

/* *et ca s'arrête là */
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="MyScript.js"></script>
    <title>CV Personnel N°1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="Monlogo">
                <img class="MonLogo_image" src="images/logoplussobre2.png" alt="Logo Jason">
            </div>
            <div class="nav-buttons">
                <div class="nav-bar-item-container">
                    <a class="nav-bar-items" href=""><span class="material-symbols-outlined nav-icon-about">task</span>Projets</a>
                </div>
                <div class="nav-bar-item-container">
                    <a class="nav-bar-items" href="..."><span class="material-symbols-outlined nav-icon-contact">local_post_office</span>Contacts</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="container">
        
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried adding a div for each anchor, as well as deleting some divs to ease the reading, but nothing worked in either case. I also tried changing the elements on the CSS part, too.

Comment: For what you are trying to achieve you might be better off with a background-image (like a flexible svg).

Comment: `.nav-bar-item-container` needs `position: relative` would be my guess.

Comment: Oh, problem solved. Thank you a lot Paulie_D (By the way thank you too Tyler for your edit) Paulie_D, I know I might me demanding but why is that that position:relative makes this possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the answer is simple. To make animation work only in hover item borders you have to add position: relative to parent element of span tag witch you add :before and :after.

```
.nav-bar-items{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.75rem;
    transition: .5s ease;
}
```

To keep the element with absolute position within the borders of it`s parent. You need to define the parent's position, e.g. relative.